# Adding IEnumerable to ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, viewstate

```
private IEnumerable<Employee> Source1;

Source1 = Function1(); // Returns Ienumerable<Employee>
ViewState.Add("str", Source1); //ERROR HERE
```

**Update**

Function1

```
 public static IEnumerable<Employee> Function1(string id)
        {
            IEnumerable<Employee> all;
            DB db = new DB(id);
            all = db.GetValues()
                .OrderByDescending(date => date.Created);
            return all;
        }

public List<Employee> GetValues()
        {
            List<string> li = database.GetFilters(id, dID.Request);
            IEnumerable<Employee> requests = Employee.GetRequests();
            List<Employee> li1 = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (string pF in li)
            {
                li1.AddRange(requests.Where(r => r.result == pF).ToList());
            }
            return li1;
        }
```

I need to make this functions serializable ?

Here, on compilation there is no error but on the page load, I get the error.

```
Error : Assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a534e089' is not marked as serializable.
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `Employee` being marked serializable (Douglas's answer), the collection itself must also be serializable. For example, if your `Function1` method returns using `yield return` instead of returning a concrete collection, you'll still have problems. If it returns an array, it should serialize just fine - but since the signature is simply `IEnumerable<Employee>`, you can't count on what type you're getting back.

For example:

```
private static IEnumerable<Employee> Function1() {
    yield return new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John" };
    yield return new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Mary" };
}

ViewState.Add("str", Source1.ToArray());
```

This will ensure that regardless of the type you got, you're serializing a simple array.

Comment: Good point.  I would advocate ensuring that you are dealing with a concrete type before attempting to save your data to session.

Comment: @Joe, You are right when I include the Function1 it is not working. I updated my answer with Function1, can you please guide me ?

Comment: You still need both solutions - you have to mark `Employee` with `[Serializable]`, and you have to make sure you're adding the object as an array or a list, not as an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the Employee class as serializable.  Session/ViewState saves complex objects by serializing them, so they need to be marked as such.

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee
```

Comment: Session/ViewState saves complex objects by serializing them, so they need to be marked as such.

Comment: Suddenly, it is not working anymore. I must be mistaken, when it ran.

Comment: I Updated the code, can you please help me solving the issue

Comment: Try `ViewState.Add("str", Source1.ToList());`